# Validateid method the else block is not working i want to check with wrong id and display error message

Tags: visualforce, javascript, community, approval-process

Validateid method the else block is not working i want to check with wrong id and display error message

```
public with sharing class ContactDetailController {

    private ApexPages.StandardController standardController;
    public string conId{get;set;}



    public ContactDetailController(ApexPages.StandardController standardController) 
    {
       this.standardController = standardController;
       conId = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('Id');


      /* Id realContId = standardController.getId();
       System.debug('-sach--'+realContId);
       if (realContId.getSObjectType() == Schema.Contact.SObjectType) {
            System.debug('This is a contact');
        } 
        else {
            System.debug('This is NOT a contact');
        }
       if(standardController.getId()==null)
       {
            ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Please enter Id on the Address Bar'));
       } */
       //this.standardController.addFields(new List<String> {'FirstName','lastname','mobilephone','Accountid','otherphone','title','fax','Department','Email','Birthdate','AssistantName','Reportstoid','Assistantphone','leadsource','OtherStreet','MailingCity','othercity','MailingState','otherstate', });

        // getDescribe that retrive whole fields of the particular object
        Schema.DescribeSObjectResult r = Contact.sObjectType.getDescribe();
        List<String>apiNames =  new list<String>();
        for(string apiName : r.fields.getMap().keySet()){
            apiNames.add(apiName);
        }
        System.debug(apiNames);
        this.standardController.addFields(apiNames);

    }
    public PageReference validateId(){
     try{  
           Id realContId= standardController.getId();
           if(Schema.Contact.SObjectType == realContId.getSobjectType())
           {
               System.debug('Try Call'+realContId);
               ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Confirm, 'Id Success'));
               return null;
           }
           else{
               ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Error, 'Id specified is not an contact id!'));
            }

       }
       catch (Exception e){
           System.debug('catch call');
           ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Error, 'No id specified!'));
           return null;
       }
       return null;
    }

    public PageReference Edit(){
        PageReference errorPage = new PageReference('/apex/ContactInsert?id='+conId);
        errorPage.setRedirect(true);
        return errorPage;
    }  
    public PageReference cloneButton(){
        // Record being cloned
        Contact con = (Contact) standardController.getRecord(); 
        // Custom clone logic
        Contact clonedcon = new Contact();
        clonedcon.FirstName = con.FirstName;
        clonedcon.lastName = con.lastName; 
        clonedcon.mobilephone = con.mobilephone;
        clonedcon.Accountid = con.Accountid;
        clonedcon.otherphone = con.otherphone;
        clonedcon.title = con.title;
        clonedcon.fax = con.fax;
        clonedcon.Department = con.Department;
        clonedcon.Email = con.Email;
        clonedcon.Birthdate = con.Birthdate;
        clonedcon.AssistantName = con.AssistantName; 
        clonedcon.Reportstoid = con.Reportstoid;
        clonedcon.Assistantphone = con.Assistantphone;
        clonedcon.leadsource = con.leadsource;
        clonedcon.OtherStreet= con.OtherStreet;
        clonedcon.MailingCity = con.MailingCity;
        clonedcon.othercity = con.othercity;
        clonedcon.MailingState = con.MailingState;
        clonedcon.otherstate = con.otherstate;
        clonedcon.MailingPostalCode = con.MailingPostalCode;
        clonedcon.otherpostalcode = con.otherpostalcode;
        clonedcon.MailingCountry = con.MailingCountry; 
        clonedcon.othercountry = con.othercountry;
        clonedcon.Languages__c = con.Languages__c;
        clonedcon.Level__c = con.Level__c;
        clonedcon.Description= con.Description;

        insert clonedcon;
        PageReference errorPage = new PageReference('/apex/ContactInsert?id='+conId);

        errorPage.setRedirect(true);
        return errorPage;
        //return new PageReference('/' +clonedcon.id+ '/e' );
        // Redirect to the new cloned record
        //return new PageReference('/'+clonedcon.Id);
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "it's not working"? What is the expected behaviour? What behaviour do you see? What have you tried so far?

Comment: i want to validate when i put the wrong id on to the url and display error message

Answer (score 0):

Try the alternative:

```
   Id realContId = standardController.getId();
   System.debug('-sach--'+realContId);
   if (realContId.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getKeyPrefix() == Schema.Contact.SObjectType.getDescribe().getKeyPrefix()) {
        System.debug('This is a contact');
   } 
   else {
        System.debug('This is NOT a contact');
   }
```

Comment: In this above code else is not working